# Makefile: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I've got this directory structure:

```
 - src
  - /GUILayer
  - /PhysicLayer
  - /LogicLayer
  - /Utilities
  - main.cpp
  - makefile
  - makefile.inc
```

And this is my current `makefile` inside of `src`:

```
include makefile.inc

DIRS    = PhysicLayer LogicLayer GUILayer Utilities
OBJLIBS = PhysicLayer.a LogicLayer.a GUILayer.a Utilities.a

EXTERNOBJ =  $(foreach path, $(DIRS), $(wildcard $(path)/*.o))

TARGETS = main.cpp 
EXE = main

all : $(EXE)

%.a :
    -for d in $(DIRS); do (cd $$d; $(MAKE)); done
    ar cr $@ $^

main: $(OBJLIBS)
    $(ECHO) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTERNOBJ) $(OBJLIBS)  -o $@ $(TARGETS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTERNOBJ) $(OBJLIBS)  -o $@ $(TARGETS) 

clean :
    -$(RM) -f ./main
    find . -name "*.o" -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f
    find . -name "*.a" -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

The files inside the folders generate the .o just fine, but the `main` doesn't generate at all.
This is the output from the terminal:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g -ggdb PhysicLayer.a LogicLayer.a GUILayer.a Utilities.a -o main main.cpp
/tmp/ccA3VJed.o: In function `main':
/home/user/Desktop/project/src/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `Indexador::Indexador()'
/home/user/Desktop/project/src/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `Indexador::indexar(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/home/user/Desktop/project/src/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `Indexador::~Indexador()'
/home/user/Desktop/project/src/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `Indexador::~Indexador()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: You should provide the actual compilation command issued. Your makefile is echoing something else, which just makes things confusing. The command you print would actually has no files to compile.

Comment: You see, this `g++ -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g -ggdb -o Bloque.o` doesn't do anything. You need some input files, and presumably you need to add a `-c` in there somewhere to compile an object file instead of an executable. It should look something like `g++ -c -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g -ggdb Bloque.cpp -o Bloque.o`

Comment: @juanchopanza, can you read the original post again? I've updated it. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

In your rule `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTERNOBJ) -c $@ $(TARGETS)` you should change `-c` to `-o`, otherwise `g++` will assume that `$@` is an input file and looks for `main`, which does not exist yet.

Comment: Ummm I still get the same error :( plus some undefined references inside `main.cpp` to one of the classes inside `LogicLayer`

Comment: You forgot to link your libraries. Can you try adding `$(OBJLIBS)` to that rule? `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTERNOBJ) $(OBJLIBS) -o $@ $(TARGETS)`

Comment: what you suggested makes sense but I still get the error? See the original post with the output from the terminal

Comment: You still didn't link your libraries. You need to add `$(OBJLIBS)` to that rule.

Comment: see current terminal output, it says `*.a: No such file or directory `

Comment: Does `-for d in $(DIRS); do (cd $$d; $(MAKE)); done` generate the desired `.a` files? Check the subdirectories. If they're there, you need to add additional commands to move them to your `src` directory or edit your `$(OBJLIBS)` variable to include subdirectories.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28937/discussion-between-l19-and-yang)